# removing icon and profile name from taskbar in Windows (10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 (although I'm not sure if that's relevant or not), and I've figured out how to do some customizations to the taskbar that I really like, namely, showing just the icons of the programs that are open instead of the icons AND the names.  But I'd also like to make my *profile name* ***disappear entirely***

[image: http://www.screencast.com/users/dborhanian/folders/Jing/media/9f30409b-3834-42f7-9b48-7215a36f8877]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For making the Profile name, I think you had made one folder same as that of the profile name, Just delete that folder and right click on the toolbar and unchecked wherever you had checked mark. that might remove that profile name